# Is it possible to mock the HttpContext for a HubCallerContext?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, signalr, httpcontext

I am attempting to mock out my SignalR hub for some unit tests. I am running into an issue on my Hubs OnConnectedAsync() call due to using a header to auto join a group if it exists. My issue is lying with the fact that the HubCallerContext.GetHttpContext() method is an extension method and cant be mocked. I dunno if there is a work around to this and I cant seem to find any similarly posted question about this.

**OnConnectedAsync() Segment**

```
Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers.TryGetValue(SignalRHeaders.GroupHeader, out StringValues header);
if (header.Any())
{
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, SignalRConstants.Group);
}
```

**Base Test Class**

```
        public DefaultHubBaseTest()
        {
            var memberId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var orgId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            MockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerClients>();
            MockClientProxy = new Mock<IClientProxy>();
            MockClients.Setup(clients => clients.Group(It.IsAny<string>()))
                    .Returns(MockClientProxy.Object);

            MockGroups = new Mock<IGroupManager>();
            MockGroups.Setup(x => x.AddToGroupAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), default(CancellationToken))).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
            MockGroups.Setup(x => x.RemoveFromGroupAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), default(CancellationToken))).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

            Mock<HttpRequest> MockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
            MockRequest.Setup(x => x.Headers).Returns(new HeaderDictionary()
            {
                { SignalRHeaders.GroupHeader, orgId },
                { SignalRHeaders.GroupAdminHeader, "t" },
            });

            Mock<HttpContext> MockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
            MockHttpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(MockRequest.Object);

            MockContext = new Mock<HubCallerContext>();
            MockContext.Setup(x => x.ConnectionId).Returns("1");
            MockContext.Setup(x => x.User.Claims).Returns(new List<Claim>() { new Claim(SignalRConstants.AzureAuthOID, memberId) });
            MockContext.Setup(x => x.GetHttpContext()).Returns(MockHttpContext.Object);

            DefaultHub = new DefaultHub()
            {
                Context = MockContext.Object,
                Groups = MockGroups.Object,
                Clients = MockClients.Object,
            };
        }
```

If anyone could help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the exact same issue and can't figure out how to get around this.

Comment: Unfortunately no. At this time it is running untested. Which is really not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by looking at what the extension method does and mocking it in the same way.

```
var context = new DefaultHttpContext();

// set up context as required
...

_mockHubCallerContext.Setup(x => x.Features.Get<IHttpContextFeature>().HttpContext).Returns(context);
```